# java swing multiple key presses disabled when one key is released

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have this car that looks like a box that can shoot bullets. If I press or hold 2 or 3 keys, they all work, but as soon as I release 1 key, everything else stop as if all the keys are released. However, if I press any or hold any of the key again, all the keys still holding start working again.

I've search and found a question that is exactly the same as mine, and it was solved by looping the run() method (in my case moveCar() method) but I'm not sure how the run() method can be loop in here.

I just now started learning java, and just doing this for practice as I go through the swing chapter, not making game or anything serious so just want to know the reason this isn't working and how to make it work.

```
public class MovingObject extends JFrame {
private BoxCar boxCar = new BoxCar();
private final int NUMKEYS = 5;

private boolean [] keys = new boolean [NUMKEYS];

public MovingObject() {
    add(boxCar);

    boxCar.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: 
                    keys[0] = true;
                    break;

                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: 
                    keys[1] = true;
                    break;

                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    keys[2] = true;
                    break;

                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    keys[3] = true;
                    break;

                case KeyEvent.VK_A: 
                    keys[4] = true;
                    break;
            }
            moveCar();
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: 
                    keys[0] = false;
                    break;

                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: 
                    keys[1] = false;
                    break;

                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    keys[2] = false;
                    break;

                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    keys[3] = false;
                    break;

                case KeyEvent.VK_A: 
                    keys[4] = false;
                    break;
            }
            moveCar();
        }
    });
    boxCar.setFocusable(true);
}

private void moveCar() {
    if(keys[0]) { 
        if(boxCar.getXCoordinate() > 20)
            boxCar.setXCoordinate(boxCar.getXCoordinate() - 20); 
    }

    if(keys[1]) { 
        if(boxCar.getXCoordinate() < (boxCar.getWidth() - boxCar.getCarWidth() - 20))
            boxCar.setXCoordinate(boxCar.getXCoordinate() + 20); 
    }

    if(keys[2]) {
        if(boxCar.getYCoordinate() > 20)
            boxCar.setYCoordinate(boxCar.getYCoordinate() - 20);
    }

    if(keys[3]) {
        if(boxCar.getYCoordinate() < (boxCar.getHeight() - boxCar.getCarHeight() - boxCar.getTireDiameter() - 20))
            boxCar.setYCoordinate(boxCar.getYCoordinate() + 20);
    }

    if(keys[4]) {   
        boxCar.setBullet();
        boxCar.setGun(true);
        Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(boxCar.bulletDistanceTravel() > boxCar.getWidth()) {
                    boxCar.setGun(false);
                }
                boxCar.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }       
}
```

Another problem is sometimes the bullet goes at a constant rate but most of the time, the bullet speed doubles on every shot?

Comment: To your second problem, you should be using a single `Timer`, not start new ones every time `keys[4]` is `true`, as they will accumulate...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, this will reduce the guess work and produce better response

Comment: oh sorry, but it looks long cause of the 4 cases that are pretty much the same thing. I just wanted to ask the questions, the code is just thrown in there just for reference.

Comment: Also, how do I do a single timer in this case? I have an array of 20 bullets each with separate xcoord and ycoord, so everytime I press A, a bullet is fired and the timer is then started for that bullet.

Comment: Basically, a single Timer would look through the array and update there positions

Comment: oh wait, instead of setting up a timer for repaint();. if I set up a timer inside the paintComponent(Graphics g), does that act as one timer or is it still one timer for every button pressed?

Comment: NO! A paint event may occur for any number of reasons, may of which you don't control. Generally speaking, you should start the Timer when the game starts and on each tick, update the state as needed. When a "fire" event occurs, update the game state to include a new bullet in the model

Comment: Cool why didn't I thought of that. Thanks! :)

Comment: Well...this is weird but after I add a timer outside then run moveCar() method inside actionPerformed method of timer, it not only fixed the second problem but fixed the first problem also haha